# How Do I Get Google Maps Activity to Show in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

My Android Studio is the latest version and does not have this activity. Is there a way to get it, or is it deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been removed from latest version of android studio. You have to add this activity manually